# fatal: unable to access....The requested URL returned error: 403

Tags: git, github

I'm attempting to push a file I created but am getting this error below.

Here are the steps I took that created the error:

```
[lsikala@localhost Salt-training]$ git add .
[lsikala@localhost Salt-training]$ git commit -am "created new file Hellopeep.txt"
[LISA d249bba] created new file Hellopeep.txt
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 Hellopeep.txt
[lsikala@localhost Salt-training]$ git push origin LISA
Username for 'https://github.com': lssikala
Password for 'https://lssikala@github.com':
```

This is the error I'm seeing.

```
remote: Permission to jeffPOG/Salt-training.git denied to lssikala.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/jeffPOG/Salt-training.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Does anyone know what is causing this error?

Comment: I doubt the user `lssikala` has push/write-access access to `https://github.com/jeffPOG/Salt-training`. Username should be `jeffPOG`.

Comment: Obvious things to check for: 1) do you actually have write access? 2) are you using your PAT (the password won't work). As @phd pointed out, 1) is probably your problem. You might have to fork the repo into your own GitHub space, or create your own repo.